# The probability that a candidate comes with all $3$ pens having the same colour is _____.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> Candidates were asked to come to an interview with $3$ pens each. Black, blue, green and red were
> the permitted pen colours that the candidate could bring. The probability that a candidate comes
> with all $3$ pens having the same colour is _____.

---

#### My Try:

Answer is given $0.2$. This question asked in GATE-16 EE set-2 paper.([See question-26 in page no.-7](http://www.gate.iisc.ernet.in/GATE2016questions/S6_EE.pdf) of section- technical and [official key given answer no.-26](http://www.gate.iisc.ernet.in/GATE2016_ans_keys_final/EE-1_AnsKey.pdf)).

I've tried according my way, but little bit tough to solve in formal way.

> Can you please explain?

Comment: "I've tried according my way" OK, where is what you tried?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that each pen is drawn with equal probability from each color (which is implied by the formulation of the question since not otherwise specified), you can use *[combinations with repetition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination#Number_of_combinations_with_repetition)*:

1. Possible ways to choose the $3$ pens: You will pick $k=3$ pens, with repetition allowed from $n=4$ colors. Order does not matter, hence combinations with repetition: $$\dbinom{n+k-1}{k}=\dbinom{4+3-1}{3}=\frac{6!}{3!3!}=20$$
2. Favorable ways to choose the $3$ pens: Obviously there are $4$ ways to pick all the pens with the same color.

Hence, the required probability is equal to $$\frac{4}{20}=0.2$$ as specified by the answer key.

Comment: Thanks for nice explanation.

Comment: You write "assuming that each pen is drawn with equal probability from each color," which suggests that you're using a I.I.D. uniform distributions for each pen, however, then you calculate something else, where you assume the set of pens is drawn uniformly from the set of possible sets (i.e. you changed from considering sequences to multisets between first paragraph and the rest). This strikes me as very misleading.

Comment: @MiloBrandt, Is it unordered partition, here? As I understood here that we have $4$ group(or boxes) of color and we need to choose in $3$ ways, So the equation became : 
$$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=3$$

Am I right?

Comment: @MithleshUpadhyay Yes, the answer here takes that all suitable choices of $x_1,\,x_2,\,x_3$ and $x_4$ are equally likely. So it's saying there are $20$ possible choices of those variables, $4$ of which give all the same color. (Which is distinct from the distribution one finds when you choose each pen randomly and independently of the others)

Answer (score 9):

This is an astoundingly badly posed problem. I would recommend not to study at the insitution that poses such problems.

No distribution has been specified, and in contrast to many other ill-posed problems that fail to specify a distribution but rely on widespread assumptions e.g. about uniform distributions, in this case it's entirely unclear which natural assumption about the habits of pen selection by candidates would lead to this answer. Reverse-engineering the answer, we can conclude that the intended meaning was that all indistinguishable selections from an unlimited supply of black, blue, green and red were equiprobable. Of the $20$ such selections, $4$ have $3$ pens of the same colour, yielding a probability $\frac4{20}=\frac15$.

Answer (score 3):

The "formal way" is to recognize that you have to count the number of ways to add four numbers to get a total of 3. For example, 1 + 0 + 2 + 0 would mean one black and two green pens. There are several methods to find that count. In this case there turn out to be 20 ways, so you could do it by listing them all if you didn't know an algebraic method (other answers tell you a formula). Of these 20 ways 4 are pens of all one colour - for example, 3 + 0 + 0 + 0 is all black. Then 4/20 = 1/5 = 0.2.

As a practical question I think the probability would be much greater, because many candidates would just have one package of pens of one colour, and bring three of them.

Comment: Thanks for nice explanation.