# The probability that a candidate comes with all $3$ pens having the same color

Tags: probability

### Question

> Candidates were asked to come to an interview with $3$ pens each.
> Black, blue, green and red were the permitted pen colours that the candidate could bring.
> The probability that a candidate comes with all $3$ pens having the same color is _________.

### My Approach

$\binom{4}{1}$ to select 1 colors from $4$ available colors and then probability of each color $ =\frac{1}{4}$

Reqd probability$  =4 \times (\frac{1}{4} )^{3}$

is it correct?

Comment: Your question lacks a lot of details needed to answer it. For example: 1) is the candidate picking randomly? 2) out of how many pens that he has? if he has 100 blue, 1 red, 1 green and no black pen, it makes a big difference. Please clarify the setting.

Comment: @laura You asked this question before. Why did you decide to post it again?

Comment: Your solution is correct *if* the probabilities of selecting each colour of pen are independent and equal. But you should state that as an assumption, as it is not part of the problem.

Comment: Oh, nice I answer the same question twice and with the same argumentation.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We can write down a sample space:

$$\Omega =\Big{\{}\{R,R,R\},\{R,R,B\}, \{R,R,G\},\{R,R,Y\},  \{R,Y,Y\}, \\ \{R,B,B\},  \{R,G,G\}, \{R,G,B\},  \{R,Y,B\}, \{R,Y,G\} , \\\{Y,Y,G\},  \{Y,Y,B\}, \{G,G,Y\},  \{G,G,B\}, \{B,B,G\},\\ \{B,G,Y\},\{B,B,Y\}, \{B,B,B\}, \{G,G,G\}, \{Y,Y,Y\}
\Big{\}}$$

So, if we assume that events are uniformly distiributed (since distribution is not mentioned in OP) we have: $$ P = {4\over |\Omega|} = {1\over 5}$$

*Please, if somebody disagree with this solution then please write down your own  sample space and distribution and then tell me what is wrong.*

Comment: its same as mine ! (?)

Comment: Yes, it is. But not sure how you  get it.

Comment: Why you take 3 colors from 4?

Comment: ahh i am really sorry! it will be $\binom{4}{1}$

Comment: @greedoid If each pen has a probability of $\frac{1}{4}$ of having a certain color, these combinations are not equally likely to occur. I cannot agree with this solution.

Comment: Now it is correct, if I didn't miss some case.

Comment: @jvdhooft No problem, just write down your sample space and we can talk then.

Comment: Surely this is only true if a candidate chooses uniformly from combination space, which isn't likely either in reality nor the setters intent. (Though the question is horribly vague). Surely it's more likely they are expected to choose independently from a set of four, three times. Once the first is chosen (freely) the others are either the same (p=0.25) or not. So 1/4^2 = 1/16, as the question setter got.

Comment: @greedoid The size of the sample space is $4^3 = 64$, as you stated before. Now you're only considering unique combinations, which do not have the same probability of occurring. Even so, there are 20 ways to combine the colors: you missed $BGY$.

Comment: And what is a difference between $(BBG)$ and $(BGB)$? @jvdhooft

Comment: @greedoid That's like asking what the difference is between $(1, 2)$ or $(2, 1)$ with two dice. The probability of one of these events happening equals $\frac{2}{36}$, while the probability of throwing $(1, 1)$ equals $\frac{1}{36}$. I agree that the question is poorly stated, but if you randomly draw a color for each pen, your original answer was correct.

Comment: How do you know that the probability for picking green is the same as for picking blue? Without clarification by the OP, the question cannot be answered at the moment and I see no point in writing up something that may be entirely unrelated. What we want for this site is people to formulate there questions in a reasonable way and provide details and attempts **before** we start answering questions. Or am I wrong?

Comment: You really can not understand that BBG and BGB makes no diffference. It has nothing to do with dice. What exactly is dice here if it does?

Comment: @greedoid Suppose we flip two coins. Would you agree that the probability of both coins coming up heads is $1/3$, since the sample space of unordered outcomes is $\{HH, HT, TT\}$?

Comment: We are not fliping coins. What are coins here? @GregoryJ.Puleo

Comment: @greedoid The pens in this problem play the same role as the coins or dice in the examples you've been shown.

Comment: @greedoid Why is my sample space incorrect? If you can tell me why HT should be different from TH, then you'll understand why people are telling you that BBG and BGB should be different.

Comment: Yes, you are right, a thought you have 1 coin fliping twice. Yes, I agree with you. @GregoryJ.Puleo

Comment: @greedoid Suppose candidate chooses the colour of each pen they take by flipping two coins, so six coin flips to choose three pens. There are $64$ equally likely possible outcomes  from flipping $6$ coins and $4$ of these lead to three pens with the same colour, so probability of three pens having the same colour is $4$ in $64$ or $1$ in $16$. Of course we aren't told *how* the candidate chooses their pens ...

Comment: @GregoryJ.Puleo But then even $B_1B_2G$ and $B_2B_3G$ is not the same if I have at least 3 blue pens. Is it not?

Comment: @greedoid Imagine being offered four colors of pens three times in a row. In each step, there are four choices, for a total of $4^3 = 64$ possible combinations. Since only four of these contain the same color, the answer is $\frac{4}{64} = \frac{1}{16}$. This is also the provided answer by GATE [here](https://d1zttcfb64t0un.cloudfront.net/gatepapers/GATE2016/EE-GATE-2016-Set-1.pdf). However, since nothing is said about how the color for each pen is chosen (maybe I just prefer the color blue?), the question is simply badly posed.

Comment: @greedoid By the way, you already answered this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2803973/probability-that-a-candidate-comes-with-all-3-pens-having-the-same-colour-is), and edited the question earlier today. Why answer it again? ;-)

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean, obviously Laura saw that change and asked again. I was not looking at the problem it self, just tags. @jvdhooft

Comment: @greedoid No worries, it was just a surprise when I googled this question and found the other thread. I voted to close as duplicate!

Comment: @greedoid Depending on the exact model, yes, we might need to (at least implicitly) distinguish between those outcomes. If I have a bag of pens from which I draw w/o replacement, then counting $B_1B_2G$ and $B_2B_3G$ as different is the only way to make bags of "100 blue pens, 1 green" and "5 blue, 1 green" give different probabilities and sample spaces of equally-probable events. W/o clarification, it seems the most natural interpretation of this problem is "each color picked independently", which needs BBG and BGB to be different if all outcomes in the sample space are to be equally likely.

Comment: @greedoid (part of the point here is that "each color picked independently* is *different* from drawing without replacement, both of which are different from your model of "each unordered triple of colors is equally likely". From the problem it's hard to tell which is correct, although it seems *likely* that each color being picked independently is the intended interpretation)