# How can I solve the problems of Combination + indistinguishable objects + repetition allowed?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Can I solve the problems of Combination with **indistinguishable** objects plus **repetition** allowed using a formula?

For instance,

> How many $3$-letter combinations could be formed from the word $BBA$ if repetition of letters is allowed?

We know the answer is $4$, as $S=\{{AAA, BBB, ABB, AAB}\}$.

Can these kinds of problems be solved using a formula, or, do I need to manually solve it every time?

**Note.** The problem in this question is different from the problem posted in [**this**](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2805217/366312) problem which I posted earlier. Here we have $2$ letters and need to produce $3$-element combinations (i.e. $n<r$). On the other hand, in the previous problem, we had $3$ letters to choose from $26$ letters (i.e. $n>r$).

Comment: A.  this particular question is entirely trivial  and B. the general question is equivalent to [your prior question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2805217/what-is-the-formula-for-combination-with-repetition)

Comment: @lulu, A.this is not about solving the problem, and B. there were no `indistinguishable objects` in the previous problem.

Comment: I don't understand.  Please edit your post to show an example illustrating the difference between the two questions.

Comment: At the moment I cannot figure out your "we know the answer ...". Why is $BBA$ not element of your set $S$? At the moment your $S$ does not seem to correspond to the description of the combinations you want to form.

Comment: @trancelocation, Coz, $BBA$ and $ABB$ are same.

Comment: I see the edit ,but I still don't understand.  It doesn't matter whether $n<r$ or not.

Comment: If you search for "weak compositions" and "stars and bars" you will find many similar examples.  I have done at least $15$ myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a so called combination with repetition. The $BBA$ is a bit misleading.

Basically you want to create $3$-multisets - multisets with $3$ items - from the set $\{A,B\}$. ("multiset" means that repetitions are allowed).

In general the number of $k$-multisets from a set of $n$ elements is 
$$\binom{n+k-1}{k}$$

In your case you have $n=2$ and $k=3$:
$$\binom{4}{3}=\frac{4!}{3!\cdot 1!} = 4$$

Comment: Yeah, I understood that later.